# Polars: groupby rolling sum

Tags: python-polars

Say I have

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({'group': [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4], 'value': [1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 4, 2, 3]})
```

I'd like to get a rolling sum, with window of 2, for each group

Expected output is:

```
┌───────┐
│ value │
│ ---   │
│ i64   │
╞═══════╡
│ 1     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 8     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5     │
└───────┘
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`.rolling_sum().over("group")`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.rolling_sum.html#polars.Expr.rolling_sum)

`min_periods=1` will fill in the nulls.

```
>>> df.select(pl.col("value").rolling_sum(2, min_periods=1).over("group"))
shape: (8, 1)
┌───────┐
│ value │
│ ---   │
│ i64   │
╞═══════╡
│ 1     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 8     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5     │
└───────┘
```